# ASP.NET: windows authentication against production server

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

This is a real quick question, is it possible to allow Windows Authentication for an ASP.Net intranet site (on a test server) to authenticate against the production server user accounts? If so, how would I go about doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are part of the same domain this is built in. If they are on separate domains, this would require a trust between the domains, and then this would be "built in" simply by prepending the domain name in front of the production user name. If they are on stand-alone machines, this gets very complicated with establishing trusts between the machines and allowing users from the "workgroup" enter. If your servers are managed by a server admin team (like most major companies), it's probable that there will be no trusts established between machines in a production domain and machines in a test domain. Many corporate security policies prohibit this interaction.

Comment: Each of the users are on the domain as well as the production server, but the test server is not. However, funny thing is that when the intranet site starts up no login screen appears (authentication mode is set to Windows) so would I have to force a login screen? I am not sure how to prepend the domain name when technically the user doesn't login to the site.

Comment: @mattgcon - If you're already using windows authentication and you're not getting a login box, then you should be able to write the `Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]` to the page to see what username is being used to view the page. This should give you an indication of where the users the machine accepts are currently entered. It's possible that the behavior you're looking for is already implemented as a part of the domain architecture.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand completely. The test server is not on a domain and the users do not exist on the test server, however they do exist on our domain. When I query to see the user logged in, it shows "TEST\xxxxxxx", which is not our domain. If no login box appears how would I tell the Test server to authenticate against the domain or does that happen within the application.

Comment: If it shows test\xxxx then that means you're logged into the test domain already. You need to log into the production domain on the machine you're using in order to get that user to appear in the LOGON_USER. That's what integrated windows authentication is about.

Comment: I understand that, but what I dont understand is, how do I force windows authentication to authenticate against the production server when the users will be testing the site against the test server.

Comment: You can't. The users must login to their machines with productiondomain\username. I'm assuming when you ran your test, you must have logged into your machine as test\xxxx.

Comment: I am not sure if you are getting the point of what I am trying to say. The website is on the test server (not connected to our domain), the users will be on their own machine logging in with domain\username to the test server to test the website out. I know I can't user that authentication on the test server, but I was wondering if there was a way to tell the test server to authenticate the user against the production server which does have domain user accounts.

Comment: @mattgcon - I do understand what you're saying, and there is a way, but it's unlikely to be approved by your security department. A trust can be established so that the test machine "trusts" the domain. Then you only need to give the domain users permission to view the website files (read should be sufficient) and their `LOGON_USER` will appear as domain\username.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand that well enough. It will easily be approved so i will see if my boss will set that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add something like this to web.config

```
 <system.web>
  ...
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  ...
 </system.web>
```

and login as SYSTEM-NAME\username and password.